# How to use Xhtml2PDF convertor in linux system?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to convert html to pdf in django using xhtml2pdf, and successfully converted html to pdf in windows but in linux it is giving me file permission error though i give all type of permission to that file.Here i am posting taht function that convert html to pdf please suggest any solution thanks in advance.

```
def CreatePDF(request):
ser_type=request.POST.get("service_type")
if ser_type  is not None:

        data=WalletTransaction.objects.get(order_id=request.POST.get("order_id"),user=request.user)
        c={'data':data,'ser_type':int(ser_type)}
        template = get_template('TransHistoryPdf.html')

        html  = template.render(c)
        file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
        pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
               encoding='utf-8')
        file.seek(0)
        pdf = file.read()
        file.close()            
        return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

Comment: Did you check folder owner/permission?